# Is there any way to not use so many Move To in my GIS model and create an array or collection of it maybe?

Tags: anylogic

I am making a GIS Model to move my agent from one point to another and I don't want to clutter my model by using too many Move To. Is there any way I can combine them, maybe in an array or collection?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this stackoverflow. How do I show you the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... just add all the destinations into a collection and then you can use this structure:

[image: structure]

use a counter for the agent... and I think the collection should be in the agent too... and just use moveTo towards `collection.get(counter)`
and on exit you do `counter++;`

and the condition to stop moving is `counter==collection.size()`

Comment: I tried doing this and It didn't work out for me. No jdea how to use the counter for the agent. Basically I am trying to move a bus from its 1st bus stop to the last. I have too many  MoveTo from one GIS Point to another - which I want to avoid on the main.

Comment: you have to add a counter variable to your agent and use agent.counter++; at the end of the moveTo block (on exit action)